# Default location of Error Log Elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I need to find the default location for the Elasticsearch error log for Ubuntu. When I start the service it states it is okay but when I ask for the service this comes up:

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendo
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-11-23 05:49:46 CST; 3min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 81608 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I need to figure out why this is happening but I don't know where the error log is located. I haven't been on this computer in a few years and I did not change it from the default location.

Comment: usually, the log is under /var/log/elasticsearch/{{clustername}}.log

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `journalctl -u elasticsearch.service -xe` first.

If this is not good look at /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service file, work out where the config is and find the log.

If *that* doesn't work install lsof and search for the log in the list of open file

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo su
cd /var/log/elasticsearch 
tail elasticsearch.log
```